# How to align table or figure caption where the table starts?

Tags: captions, horizontal-alignment, width

HI

How can I start the caption where table starts or figure starts?

```
\captionsetup{justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false}
```

does not work for me because it places the caption at the beginning of the paragraph not the beginning of the table.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow,blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{\blindtext}\label{foo}}
  {\includegraphics{bar}}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[!htb]
\ttabbox{\caption{A not so long caption.}\label{bar}}
        {\begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
            foo & bar & baz \\\hline
         \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any ideas about tables?

Comment: @Aharoun: maybe that you are able to replace `figure` with `table` and `ffigbox` with `ttabbox` ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert: The definition of `\ttabbox` is `\floatbox[\captop]{table}[\FBwidth]`, so you don't need to specify `[\FBwidth]` explicitly. (Contray to that, `\ffigbox` equates to  `\floatbox{figure}`.)

Comment: @lockstep: true, I shouldn't use copy and paste ... ;-) thanks

Comment: Thanks again, When I compile your code only, it works fine but when I use \usepackage{floatrow} in my document (my work), it gives me this error: ! Package floatrow Error: Do not use float package with floatrow.(floatrow) The latter will be skipped.

Comment: @Aharoun: the message says it all: "Do not use package float"!

Comment: I am not using float package Float at all! this is what I am using
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics,amsmath,amssymb,epsfig,makeidx,tabularx,lscape, here, verbatim, graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut,rotating,ctable}

Comment: @Aharoun: it is the package `here`. Do not laod it, it is really outdated. However, youl shouldn't load also not `epsfig`, also outdated and do not load packages several times ..

Comment: HI Herbert, thank for your recommendations. I followed all of them. The code now can compiled with no problems. However, the original problem have not been solved yet. The problem is the length of the table is longer than the length of caption. Refer to your example, if you reduce the length of your caption to "not long caption" and add another two columns to your table; The caption stays at the centre of the table while I want it just start from the edge of the table. I hope I am clear enough this time. I do apologise for all this but I am still a beginner. Many thanks Herbert!

Comment: @Aharoun: insert before you load the package `floatrow` this: `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}`